# How to limit Simple Deform Modifiers

Tags: modifiers

i had problem with my object.
I want bend my object only on top, i already try (Limits, Vertex Group on Restriction section, and Origin) but cannot solve my problem.
Maybe someone can help me solve this problem ?
Thank You Before

**Problem, from top to bottom all bended**

[image]

**My objective**

[image]

Comment: tbh i would not use a simple deform but a curve modifier...that's much easier to achieve. Is there a special reason why you wanna use the simple deform modifier? example: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8mp9.gif for animation just animate the z coordinate of the curve (in my case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can limit the influence of the deform modifiers using vertex groups, but you need enough starting geometry to work with, so you need to subdivide the mesh and not relying on SubSurf Modifier only.

Then, as stated by Chris, this kind of modeling is better performed by a curve modifier, so to have control on the exact final shape.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping me. 
But, why when i deform object (my object already bevel before on the corner) , the object have many line inside ?  https://i.imgur.com/VFc4dzK.png

Comment: Apply rot and scale to every object and curve before using modifiers (Ctrl A in object mode). Then check for overlapping unwanted geometry (Edit mode, select all, M to merge by distance). In curve modifier the Deform axis should be set to Z or - Z if all rot are applied.